# TypeScript linter warning: no-unused-variable is deprecated; but I'm not using this config

Tags: typescript, tslint

Today I see this warning in a project being refreshed after 3 months.

> no-unused-variable is deprecated. Since TypeScript 2.9. Please use the built-in compiler checks instead.

But my `tsconfig.json` does not seem to use this.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "allowJs" : true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Probably it's a config implicit in any of the previous configs.

Could you point me to what to do to fix it?

If usefull

```
$ node -v
v10.3.0
$ npm -v
6.1.0
```

And these are `devDependencies` relates to type script in my `package.json`

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^2.9.1"
    ...
  },
```

Comment: It's a TSLint warning. Look in the `tslint.json` file for the rule configurations.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

> no-unused-variable is deprecated. Since TypeScript 2.9. Please use the built-in compiler checks instead.

1. Remove deprecated `no-unused-variable` from your or dependency
   *[tslint.json](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-unused-variable/)*
   file.
2. Specify the following compiler options in your
   *[tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)*
   file.

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
  "noUnusedParameters": true             /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
}
```

Comment: Tested. Best answer.

Comment: how to use this rule inline? that my question.

Comment: thank you! I was confused as I thought tsc compilation reads eslint rules, and I had no-unused-vars turned off there, but it turns out that I need this in tsconfig

Answer (score 37):

As it says, tslint deprecated that rule (more info here https://github.com/palantir/tslint/pull/3919)

Check your `tslint.json`, and remove the rule and the warning should disappear.

Comment: Thanks. I checked `tsconfig.json` _but not checked_ `tslint.json`.

Comment: But what does `Please use the built-in compiler checks instead.` mean?

Comment: @ThomasEbert this means adding `noUnusedLocals`/`noUnusedParameters` to `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: @migg has the real answer here. Don't just remove the rule without adding this.

Comment: This doesn't seem like it should be deprecated, though, as `noUnusedLocals` does NOT catch unused imports, while `no-unused-variable` DOES catch unused imports.

Answer (score 9):

Not only support for `no-unused-variable` rule, but the whole [TSLint has been deprecated](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4100#issuecomment-517532286) in favor of [typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint).

Consider [migration](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534) to new linter.

Comment: Note that at the time of writing of this comment, Angular is still uses TSLint by default. The migration for Angular is still in progress. So Angular users might still want to stick TSlint for a short while until the Angular team is done with migrating.