# What does 'Please use the built-in compiler checks instead.' mean?

Tags: typescript, tslint

My app has two warnings from lint:

```
no-use-before-declare is deprecated. Since TypeScript 2.9. Please use the built-in compiler checks instead.
no-unused-variable is deprecated. Since TypeScript 2.9. Please use the built-in compiler checks instead.
```

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51621162/typescript-linter-warning-no-unused-variable-is-deprecated-but-im-not-using-t) and [this](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/pull/3919) and [this](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4046), etc... I gather there's a big migration going on in lint-land.  Unfortunately, `Please use the built-in compiler checks` is still super vague.

Is it possible to migrate these two options to eliminate the warnings and keep the functionality?

Answer (score 2):

"Built-in compiler checks" means enabling `noUnusedLocals` and `noUnusedParameters` compiler options in tsconfig.json. But I wouldn't bother since then they will be hard errors that prevent compilation, and cannot be turned into warnings.

> I gather there's a big migration going on in lint-land.

Yes. From tslint to [typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint):

> Palantir, the backers behind TSLint announced earlier this year that
>   they would be deprecating TSLint in favor of supporting
>   typescript-eslint in order to benefit the community. You can read more
>   about that here:
>   https://medium.com/palantir/tslint-in-2019-1a144c2317a9
>
> The TypeScript Team themselves also announced their plans to move the
>   TypeScript codebase from TSLint to typescript-eslint, and they have
>   been big supporters of this project. More details at
>   https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30553

Comment: Could not find implementations for the following rules specified in the configuration:
    noUnusedLocals
    noUnusedParameters
Try upgrading TSLint and/or ensuring that you have all necessary custom rules installed.
If TSLint was recently upgraded, you may have old rules configured which need to be cleaned up.

Comment: As of this writing, I'm using latest tslint (5.20.1).

Comment: @jsharpe tsconfig.json, not tslint.json.